# Java Exception Handling best practices

Tags: java

I am throwing an exception `NotFoundException` in my controller to check whether an Object (Building here) is existent in my Database or not and send the `404` HTTP Status like so :

```
 try {
            Building building = buildingComponent.getBuildingById(id);
            if (building != null) {
                return ok(buildingComponent.getBuildingById(id));
            } else {
                throw new NotFoundException("");
            }

        }

        catch (Exception e) {

            // handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
            if (e.getClass().getCanonicalName().equals("javassist.NotFoundException")) {
                return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).body(null);
            } else {
                return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body(null);
            }
        }
```

I want to know if throwing and catching the exception like i did (by comparing the canonical name of the exception) is a good exeption handling practise in java spring.

EDIT : i found the solution : it is to catch multiple times (the `NotFoundException` and others) like this :

```
catch (NotFoundException e) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).body(null);
        }

        catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body(null);

        }
```

Thank you,

Comment: No it isn't. Just catch the exception and check the type (or a specific catch for the type). Or just let it bubble up and write a proper exception handler.

Comment: how to check the type in the catch block

Comment: Catch the most specific exception first. Do not look at the name - it will break if you refactor.

Comment: how to catch by the type not the name ??

Comment: Use the type in the catch statement.  Please read up on catch statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this code There can be two solutions:

1. No need to throw the exception and handle it by identifying the
   exception, You can write like this:

   ```
   try {
       Building building = buildingComponent.getBuildingById(id);
       if (building != null) {
           return ResponseEntity.ok(buildingComponent.getBuildingById(id));
       } else {
           return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).body(null);
       }
   } catch (Exception e) {
       return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body(e.getMessage());
   }
   ```
2. Instead of writing if else in the controller you can throw the exception from the `buildingComponent` itself and handle the exception later like below.

   ```
    try {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(buildingComponent.getBuildingById(id));
    } catch (NotFoundException e) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).body(null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body(null);
    }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

No, this doesn't make a whole lot of sense in multiple ways.

1. You're throwing the exception just to immediately catch it. If you already know there's an error just go ahead and return an error response:

   ```
   if (building != null) {
     return ok(buildingComponent.getBuildingById(id));
   } else {
     return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).body(null);
   }
   ```
2. There is a built in way to catch exceptions of a specific type. You should specify exceptions being caught from most specific to least specific:

   ```
   try {
     // do something
   } catch(NotFoundException e) {
     // do some error handling
   } catch(Exception e) {
     // catch other exceptions 
   }
   ```

Comment: Looks like code formatting is broken? Had to put in 8 spaces insted of 4

Comment: You are in a list.

Comment: Would've expected the automatic code formatting button to handle it, but I got it working anyway

Comment: the problem is that i want to catch the NotFoundException  and the others as well

Comment: See the edit. Though if there is another exception, Spring will generally automatically return a 500 anyway, so doing it manually is mostly unnecessary[

Answer (score 0):

To map an exception to a status code they are multiple way to do it with spring:

- The simple one is to just let your exception to be propagated and add `@ResponseStatus` to its definition. In your case `@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUD)` and let ResponseStatusExceptionResolver handle it.
- You can create your own HandlerExceptionResolver ([more in the doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.7.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-exceptionhandlers))
- You can use [@ExceptionHandler](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.7.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-exceptionhandler)

a full example:

```java
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionHandling {
    @ExceptionHandler
    public ResponseEntity<String> handle(Exception ex) {
        if (ex instanceof NotFoundException) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).body(null);
        } else {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body(null);
        }
    }
}

@Controller
public class MyController {
    public ResponseEntity<String> myMethod() {
            Building building = buildingComponent.getBuildingById(id);
            if (building != null) {
                return ok(buildingComponent.getBuildingById(id));
            } else {
                throw new NotFoundException("");
            }
    }
}
```

Make NotFoundException a RuntimeException to avoid throws definition.

More about [@ControllerAdvice](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.7.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-controller-advice). You should really look at the documentation you will find everything.

Comment: can you illustrate a full example for the ExceptionHandler in my Building example pls ?

Comment: what about the catch block where to add it using this code ?

Comment: I updated my answer with a full sample. But everything can be found in the link I gave you

Comment: well it's working for me you must have some configuration issue